# Sum multiple NumericUpDown controls to a label text

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a row of NumericUpDown boxes with a Label in a Form and I would like to display the total of all the NumericUpDown values in the Label.

I know I can add a small piece of code in each NumericUpDown on ValueChange that will then return the sum in the label but I want to try and avoid repeating the same piece of code.

Is there a way of writing a class that can be called into the NumericUpDown on ValueChange to make it easier to maintain.

Current piece of code that is repeated For Each NumericUpDown:

```
private void num_Personal_NumbericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.lbl_Personal_label1.Text = (
    this.num_Personal_NumbericUpDown1.Value +
    this.num_Personal_NumbericUpDown2.Value +
    this.num_Personal_NumbericUpDown3.Value +
    this.num_Personal_NumbericUpDown4.Value +
    this.num_Personal_NumbericUpDown5.Value
  ).ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create separated method for `NumericUpDown` controls `ValueChanged` events:

```cs
private void NumericUpDown_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Do the sum and display magic. It will be continued below.
}
```

And add it as `delegate` to rule them all, instead of calling your controls manually:

```
foreach (NumericUpDown control in Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>())
{
    control.ValueChanged += NumericUpDown_ValueChanged;
}
```

So currently there is so all that remains is to define the logic in your method, for example using LINQ [`Sum()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sum) method:

```cs
private void NumericUpDown_ValueChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal sum = Controls.OfType<NumericUpDown>().Sum(control => control.Value);
    lbl_Personal_label1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

And here you go! Changing `Value` of any `NumericUpDown` in your form will trigger `ValueChanged` event which will calculate current sum of controls values.

---

EDIT: to make my answer to comment more readable:

> Is there a way of specifying which NumericUpDown's in the code?

You can create any specific controls collection that implements [`IEnumerable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable) to make it still easy, e.g. an array. Just put here chosen controls:

```cs
var someControlsArray = new NumericUpDown[]
{
    num_Personal_NumbericUpDown2,
    num_Personal_NumbericUpDown3 // etc
};

decimal chosenControlsSum = someControlsArray.Sum(control => control.Value);
```

Comment: Thank you that is great. I do have another total box which is to just sum the total of the NumericUpDown field mention as well. Is there a way of specifying which NumericUpDown's in the code?

Comment: EDIT: i moved my comment to answer to make it more readable :)